# How to find points in a certain distance to a Latitude/Longitude Coordinate

Tags: geometry, coordinates, trigonometry

I'm working with Latitude/Longitude Coordinates and i'm trying to find an equation for a circle on the surface that includes all points that have a certain distance(on the surface) from the center.

It's important that this should work also with very big distances (for example half the perimeter of the earth), so the flat-earth approximation probably won't work, but assuming it's a perfect sphere is okay.

Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have this very same problem. 
What I do is to convert the latitude and longitude to Cartesian coordinates fixed at the center of the Earth (which I assume is spherical).
I interpret these coordinates as a mathematical vector.
I also convert the desired "distance from center of circle"
to an angle at the center of the Earth,
that is, if the distance is `d` then the angle is `alpha = d/R`
where `R` is the Earth's radius.

I then find three vectors. 
The first vector, `v1`, is just `cos(alpha)` times my original vector,
that is, it points from the center of the Earth to the center of my circle
and it has length `R*cos(alpha)`.
The other two vectors, `v2` and `v3`, have length `R*sin(alpha)`, 
and they are both perpendicular to `v1` and to each other.

I can then get any point on the desired circle by taking

```
    v1 + cos(beta)*v2 + sin(beta)*v3
```

where `beta` can range from 0 to 2*pi.
Finally, if I want the latitude and longitude of that point,
I convert it back from Cartesian coordinates.

If you never actually care about the Cartesian coordinate model but will
instead use *only* the latitudes and longitudes that result,
you can simplify the procedure slightly by assuming `R == 1`.
You can then simplify the formulas so that you never have to define
the variable `R`.

The coordinate conversions in either direction can be fairly straightforward.
An easy way to find vector `v2` is to take the x and y coordinates of `v1`
(ignoring z), rotate the resulting vector 90 degrees in the x-y plane
(so if you started with (x,y,z), the new vector is (-y,x,0)),
and then scale the vector to the desired size.
Of course if the x and y coordinates of `v1` are zero then you can
let `v2` be any vector in the x-y plane.
To get `v3` you can take the cross product of `v1` and `v2` and scale
as desired.

Comment: Thanks! This seems pretty good! However i'm stuck trying to calculate v2. Lets say i have (1,2,3), then i take x and y (1,2), rotate it by 90 degrees (-2, 1), but how do i make a 3D-Vector out of it?

Comment: The vector v2 is always a 3-D vector, but the z coordinate has been set to zero and stays zero. Of course v3 then usually ends up with a non-zero z coordinate, but the cross-product will help with that.